# Angular Router Child dosent render

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

In my app.module.ts i have declared a child router component.
When i want to navigate to this point, it will changed the url like expected but the html dosent render.

```
import { UserComponent } from './admintiles/user/user.component';
...
{
path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], resolve: {
  user: UserResolve
},
children: [
  { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], resolve: {
    user: UserResolve
  }, data: {roles: 'Admin'}
},
],
data: {roles: 'Admin'}
```

}

User Component

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http:HttpClient) { }
  user: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data) => { 
      this.user = data.user;
    }); 
  }

}
```

admmin.component.html

```
    <div class="tiles">
      <div class="userTile" [routerLink]="['user']">
          <div class="tileContainer">
          ...
```

Can someone spot my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to angular documentation, when [Nesting Routes](https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes) , you should also include a

> second < router-outlet > in addition to the one in AppComponent.

In your case, `AdminComponent` is the parent route and `UserComponent` is the child route, which is going to be rendered inside the `AdminComponent`. To indicate Angular where you want the component to be rendered exactly, use a second `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

admin.component.html

```
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="userTile" [routerLink]="['user']">
    <div class="tileContainer">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>  // UserComponent template will be rendered here 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also bear in mind this child routes approach will not allow you to render the multiple children all at once. So maybe you wish to evolve your code so you can get choose in a flexible manner which child component to be rendered and still apply the styles from the `tileContainer`.

```
<ul class="tilesNavigation">
  <li><a routerLink="user-type-1">User type 1</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="user-type-2">User type 2</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="user-type-3">User type 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tileContainer">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>  // Child templates will be rendered here 
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect - now the html will be rendered in my admin component, but than my understanding is for Child routes is wrong. I wanted to show a complete new site and not in the html from my admin site :)

Comment: Indeed, child routes are to be used when parent and children components have some connected logic. For example, when inside the parents product page (/products), you will then show different products by id (/products/:id). 
Depending on how big is your application, consider splitting your logic into different modules further than having a unique app.component.ts.